How is Brayton cycle heat injection isobaric?
I'm trying to analyze a gaseous working fluid at the exit of the heating chamber as it heads to a nozzle in a Brayton cycle. My understanding is that the injection of heat creates a rise in internal-energy/enthalpy which manifests as a rise in temperature/pressure (the density is not allowed to change in for a fixed mass inside a fixed control volume). How can one reconcile this rise in pressure with the alleged fact that the heat injection is an isobaric process?
In practice, how do we handle this? Do we solely look at the temperature rise (based on the enthalpy) and use the combustion chamber outlet temperature to derive the outlet pressure using e.g. ideal gas law?

Are you sure your description is correct? See https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/brayton.html

@BobD Ahh seems I failed to mention this is for a rocket engine so there would be no turbine - so it would be different than that provided by your link.
